# Clarification on entering the US on B2, leaving to Mexico and re-entering the US on F1

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

To provide more context: I am a Malaysian citizen & holding a Malaysian passport so I don't qualify for the VWP. However, I hold both a valid B2 visa & an F1 visa. My i-20 states that the earliest I can enter the US on an F1 visa is the 19th of July. However, I planned to visit the US a week earlier on the 10th of July to sort out my accommodation before I re-enter as I will be starting my assistantship and I want to be prepared. I plan to leave for Cancun Mexico on the 16th of July and return on the 19th of July with my F1 visa. Just wanted to clarify is this allowed?

Comment: just corrected it! it's a b2 visa for tourism/visit purposes

Comment: "My i-20 states that the earliest I can enter the US on an F1 visa is the 19th of July": should we infer from this statement that the "program start date" is August 18th?